# Plot a function after taking the supremum with respect to one variable

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

Assume given a continuous function $f$ with 2 variables, say $x$ and $y$. $x$ takes values on the interval $I$ and $y$ takes values on the interval $J$. I would like to know how to plot the function 
$$g(y):=\sup_{x\in I}f(x,y)$$
 using Mathematica. For example, $f(x,y)=e^y\sin(x^2)$ with $x\in[0,1], y\in[0,1]$. Many thanks.

Comment: Give us an example of an `f`. Give us an idea of where you are. Do you know how to plot functions in general? Do you know how to take the supremum of a function in *Mathematica* (if such a thing is possible)? Etc.

Comment: @march So far I know that using `Plot` to plot the graph of a single variable function and `MaxValue` to find out the maximum value of a function on an interval. I am a beginner of using mathematica.

Answer (score 10):

There are multiple ways. Here's one. (I chose this new function because it's a little more interesting).

```
f[x_, y_] = Exp[2 x] Exp[-2 y] Cos[15 x y]
```

Then, define

```
g[y_?NumericQ] := MaxValue[{f[x, y], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

or

```
g[y_?NumericQ] := First@NMaximize[{f[x, y], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

in which case

```
Plot[g[y], {y, 0, 1}]
```

yields

[image]

after a little bit of time. To get a better picture of this, define instead the function that gives us the 3D point, i.e.

```
g3D[y_?NumericQ] := NMaximize[{f[x, y], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

make a `Table` of points via

```
vals = Riffle[{x /. #2, #1} & @@ g3D@#, #] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.02];
```

and then plot:

```
Show[
 Plot3D[f[x, y],
   {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Mesh -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None
  ],
 Graphics3D[Line@vals]
]
```

[image]

Comment: You could've used `NMaxValue[]` for the third snippet. ;)

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive, could you take a look at my recent question where I have two variables to optimize over: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193867/optimization-problem