# How to maximize just with respect two parameters out of four?

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

There are some posts explaining how do we maximize a function of two parameters with respect to one of those and how to plot the resulting function: [Plot a function after taking the supremum with respect to one variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110201/plot-a-function-after-taking-the-supremum-with-respect-to-one-variable).

Now I have a quite complicated function which has four parameters: $(n,t,\theta,\phi)$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is natural, $t\in (-1,1)$ and $(\theta,\phi)\in S^2$ are angles on the sphere.

The function is highly non trivial. It is the output of computations involving matrices, eigenvalues, and a bunch of things like that. The $n$ is the dimension of the matrix, which acts as a cuttoff to get an approximation to the real computation with operators on a Hilbert space (so one is actually truncating to dimension $n$).

Now I need to maximize with respect to $(\theta,\phi)$ and get a function of $(n,t)$ that for each $n$ fixed can be plotted.

I believe that numerically there sould be no issue in doing that. The method of the question didn't work however. Calling `preClassicalCorrelationsAB[nmax_Integer, t_, th_, phi_]` the four-argument function, I tried:

```
f[nmax_Integer, t_?NumericQ] := NMaximize[{preClassicalCorrelationsAB[nmax, t, th, phi], 0 <= th <= Pi, 0 <= phi <= 2 Pi}, t]
```

And tried plotting `f` for fixed `nmax = 100`. It didn't work. In particular I got the error:

> 0.05102712269051777` is not a valid variable.

The same happend with `MaxValue`.

I mean, I know the function is highly complicated and so on, but *numerically* it should be possible to handle it.

So, how can I proceed to maximize this function with respect to $(\theta,\phi)$ and get a function of $(n,t)$ which I can plot for any value of $n$?

**Edit**: The comment showed I was using `NMaximize` in the wrong way. Still, I have a problem due to the kind of function I'm considering. The code defining is as follows. First two helper functions are defined:

```
cs = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, If[0. < x < 1., x Log[2, x], 0.], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]
myEigenvalues[mat_SparseArray?SquareMatrixQ] := If[mat["NonzeroPositions"] === {} && mat["Background"] == 0., ConstantArray[0., Length[mat]], Eigenvalues[N[mat], Method -> "Banded"]]
```

Next one defines the matrices `rhoBPostAPlus` and `rhoBPostAMinus`. Finally one defines:

```
probPlus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_, phi_] :=Tr[rhoBPostAPlus[nmax, t, th, phi]]
probMinus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_, phi_] := Tr[rhoBPostAMinus[nmax, t, th, phi]]
rhoBPostAPlusNormalized[nmax_Integer, t_, th_, phi_] := rhoBPostAPlus[nmax, t, th, phi]/probPlus[nmax, t, th, phi]
rhoBPostAMinusNormalized[nmax_Integer, t_, th_, phi_] := rhoBPostAMinus[nmax, t, th, phi]/probMinus[nmax, t, th, phi]

entropyBPostAPlus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_, phi_] :=Total[cs@myEigenvalues[rhoBPostAPlusNormalized[nmax, t, th, phi]]]
entropyBPostAMinus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_, phi_] := Total[cs@myEigenvalues[rhoBPostAMinusNormalized[nmax, t, th, phi]]]

preClassicalCorrelationsAB[nmax_Integer, t_, th_, phi_] := entropyB[nmax, t] + probPlus[nmax, t, th, phi]*entropyBPostAPlus[nmax, t, th, phi] + probMinus[nmax, t, th, phi]*entropyBPostAMinus[nmax, t, th, phi]
```

This `preClassicalCorrelationsAB` works perfectly if I try to evaluate it. We can even plot it without error.

Now when we evaluate:

```
f[nmax_Integer, t_?NumericQ] := NMaximize[{preClassicalCorrelationsAB[nmax, t, th, phi],0 <= th <= Pi, 0 <= phi <= 2 Pi}, {th, phi}]
```

we get the error:

```
NMaxValue::nnum: The function value -1.90526-0.5 
((0<Eigenvalues[SparseArray[Automatic,<<3>>],Method->Banded]<1.)+1.4427
Eigenvalues[SparseArray[<<1>>],<<1>>]
Log[Eigenvalues[<<1>>,Method->Banded]])-0.5
((0<Eigenvalues[SparseArray[Automatic,{11,11},0,
{1,{{0,2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29,31},{{2},{1},{1},{3},{2},{2},{4},{3},{3},{5},{4},{4},{6},{5},{5},{7},{6},{6},{8},{7},{7},{9},{8},{8},{10},{9},{9},{11},{10},{10},{11}}},
{Times[<<4>>],Times[<<2>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<2>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<2>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<2>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<2>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<2>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<2>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<2>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<2>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<2>>],Times[<<4>>],Times[<<2>>]}}],Method->Banded]<1.)+1.4427
Eigenvalues[SparseArray[<<1>>],Method->Banded]
Log[Eigenvalues[SparseArray[Automatic,{11,11},0,{1,{<<2>>},
{<<31>>}}],Method->Banded]]) is not a number at {phi,th} =
{6.20181,2.61304}.
```

Why is that? `NMaximize` can't handle a function like that?

Comment: I would think that your call to `NMaximize` within the definition of `f` should read: `NMaximize[{func, cons}, {th, phi}]`, i.e. you should NOT be trying to maximize with respect to `t`, but with respect to $\theta$ and $\phi$. `t` is a numerical value by the time the `NMaximize` call is evaluated.

Comment: What is `rhoBPostAPlus [ ]` in your code? The function is undefined. Same for `entropyB` and `rhoBPostAMinus`.

Comment: `rhoBPostAPlus` is a matrix which depends on the four parameters. I didn't add it to avoid making the post even lengthier, since its definition is rather complicated. The same for `rhoBPostAMinus`. Intuitively I thought the problem couldn't be with them, since the `preClassicalCorrelationsAB` function works on its own, being even possible to plot it.

Comment: Try forcing the `preClassicalCorrelationsAB` function to not run until it has numeric values, so use `preClassicalCorrelationsAB[nmax_Integer, t_?NumericQ, th_?NumericQ, phi_?NumericQ]`

Comment: If you can simulate the behavior with a simplified `rhoBPostAPlus` we can probably solve this in minutes.

Comment: With your suggestion it works. It is possible to even evaluate the function at specific values of `nmax` and `t`. Just plotting it isn't possible. Indeed, Mathematica says it wasn't possible to converge in 100 iterations. I tried setting to 1000 or more, and it still can't do it. I think that perhaps it simply isn't possible to do it with a complicated function like that.

Comment: See my updated answer for the `Plot` issue. Best of luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a function to play with...

```
preClassicalCorrelationsAB[nmax_, t_, th_, phi_] := -(nmax^2 + t^2 + th^2 + phi^2)
```

Then define

```
f[nmax_Integer, t_?NumericQ] := NMaximize[preClassicalCorrelationsAB[nmax, t, th, phi], {th, phi}] // First
```

We are optimizing over `th` and `phi` with `n` and `t` fixed, then picking off the value of the function with the `First` call.

Try it.

```
f[2, 2]
```

> -8

EDIT: just saw @MarcoB's comment, which is the answer too.

Another EDIT: bringing the answer down from the comments.

When you get these sorts of issues, they can often be addressed by forcing the kernel function of the optimization to only operate with numerical values.

```
preClassicalCorrelationsAB[nmax_Integer, t_?NumericQ, th_?NumericQ, phi_?NumericQ]
```

If you are having trouble using a `Plot` command on the function, and know that the function is reasonably smooth, you can try `ListPlot3D@Table[etc.,{  }]` as a workaround that lets you control the  sampling interval.