# Optimization problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have the following function

```
myfun[θ_, ϕ_, t_] =
  (1/(2*Log[2]))*
   (Log[2] -
     (Log[1/2 - ((1/2)*Sqrt[E^(2*I*ϕ)*
               (Cos[θ]^2 + ((Cos[0.099995*t] + 
                    0.0100005*Sin[0.099995*t])^2*Sin[θ]^2)/
                  E^(0.002*t))])/E^(I*ϕ)]*
        Sqrt[E^(2*
             I*ϕ)*(Cos[θ]^2 + ((Cos[0.099995*t] + 
                  0.0100005*Sin[0.099995*t])^2*Sin[θ]^2)/
             E^(0.002*t))])/E^(I*ϕ) + 
     Log[ (1/2)*(1 - 
          Sqrt[Cos[θ]^2 + ((Cos[0.099995*t] + 
                  0.0100005*Sin[0.099995*t])^2*Sin[θ]^2)/
             E^(0.002*t)])]*(-1 + 
        Sqrt[Cos[θ]^2 + ((Cos[0.0 .099995*t] + 
                0.0100005*Sin[0.099995*t])^2*Sin[θ]^2)/
           E^(0.002*t)]) - 
     Log[(1/2)*(1 + 
          Sqrt[Cos[θ]^2 + ((Cos[0.099995*t] + 
                  0.0100005*Sin[0.099995*t])^2*Sin[θ]^2)/
             E^(0.002*t)])]*(1 + 
        Sqrt[Cos[θ]^2 + ((Cos[0.099995*t] + 
                0.0100005*Sin[0.099995*t])^2*Sin[θ]^2)/
           E^(0.002*t)]) + 
     Log[(1/2)*(1 + 
          Sqrt[E^(2*
                I*ϕ)*(Cos[θ]^2 + ((Cos[0.099995*t] + 
                    0.0100005*Sin[0.099995*t])^2*Sin[θ]^2)/
                E^(0.002*t))]/E^(I*ϕ))]*(1 + 
        Sqrt[E^(2*
              I*ϕ)*(Cos[θ]^2 + ((Cos[0.099995*t] + 
                   0.0100005*Sin[0.099995*t])^2*Sin[θ]^2)/
              E^(0.002*t))]/E^(I*ϕ)));
```

I want to maximize over $\theta$ and $\phi$, with $0 \le \theta\le \pi$ and $0 \le \phi \le 2\pi$. How can this be done?

Comment: Have a look at the documentations of `NMaximize` and `FindMinimum`.

Comment: Thanks, @HenrikSchumacher. But what to do with the variable t?

Comment: So, you need symbolic solutions? (Do you realize that _it would have been helpful to put that into you post?_) You _may_ try `Maximize` but I doubt that it will produce readible output. Better use `NMaximize` for numerical values of `t`.

Comment: A relevant post (but it has only one optimization parameter and I have two) is here; https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110201/plot-a-function-after-taking-the-supremum-with-respect-to-one-variable

Comment: I would start considering if I can use the Weierstrass substitution for this problem.

Comment: The repeated constants, 0.0100005 and 0.099995, look like machine precision approximations to 1/100 and 1/10. Should that be true, replacing the machine precision numbers with their exact rational values would be good thing to do.

Comment: Do you realize the partial derivative with respect to ϕ is zero?  (It's piecewise constant as a function of ϕ.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just want to explore some plots of your function.  It seems easy to understand from that point of view:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[myfun[θ, ϕ, t] // ReIm // Evaluate,
  {ϕ, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {θ, -Pi, Pi}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> t, MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotRange -> All],
 {t, -10, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled", SynchronousUpdating -> False},
  ContinuousAction -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]